# Calling constructor in c# for a second time

Tags: c#, constructor

Is it possible to call a constructor for a second time, like this:

```
public ClassName()
{
    Value = 10;
}

public void Reset()
{
    // Reset
    ClassName();
}
```

Or is this the only way:

```
public ClassName()
{
    Reset();
}

public void Reset()
{
    // Reset
    Value = 10;
}
```

Comment: Why not just try it ? Also if you want to change Value, why not just make it property and change it when you like it.

Comment: why you want to call it 2 times?

Comment: Well you can place a call to constructor in initializer block. So, In this way whenever object is created first initializer block will run and afterwards your constructor will run

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to call constructor many times by using Reflection because constructor is a kind of special method, so you can call it as a method.

```
public void Reset()
{
    this.GetType().GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(this, new object[] { });
}
```

**HENCE**: **this is not how you should do it**. If you want to *reset* object to some default settings, just make some helper, private method for it, called from constructor also:

```
public ClassName()
{
    Defaults();
}

public void Reset()
{
    Defaults();
}

private void Defaults()
{
    Value = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why would you like to call the constructor multiple times? A constructor is intended to initialize a new object, and therefore is only called upon creation of the object.
If you would like to re-use this logic, you will have to put it into a separate method and call it from the constructor. Otherwise you should create a new instance of the object instead, and assign it to the same variable.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to call the constructor two times without using reflection as it's called only once to construct the object.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx)

> Instance constructors are used to create and initialize any instance member variables when you use the new expression to create an object of a class.

So you can only go with the second approach.

Comment: it is definitely possible using reflection. -1

Comment: What sense makes accepting an answer that says that correct answer is in another answer?